# How to remove Cached Domain Accts from Workstations which are deleted in AD?

Tags: windows

I have been trying to resolve this issue for months not, of course on and off

I have a domain environment where a domain user automatically used to login on those machines.

But I had to change the passwords so not it gives Password Incorrect error when trying to login so I have to manually enter the password when logging in every time.

To Solve that Issue I deleted the user "admin" and created a new user "staff"

Now when I reboot the computer admin account still tries to log in giving incorrect password error. Please let me know what to do I really am stumped

Here are the things that I have tried so far:

1. Checked Domain GPO
2. Local Security Policies
   3: User Accounts > Advanced > Manage Passwords (Nothing Strange)
3. net user to see if that shows anything
4. rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr

No.2 on the server was filled with usernames so I deleted all of those entries.

I have searched the net for hours and couldn't find much detail on this. Please Let me know how to please. Thanks a million in Advanced.

Comment: Do you know how the workstation is configured to automatically login? Navigate in the Registry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and look for the values **DefaultUserName** and **DefaultPassword**. Are these set to the incorrect username & password? Fix them if so.

Comment: i tried that this morning, took me a while to figure this out..thanks twisty